# Foreach from array json data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get an array in JSON format and I decode this data. I can access to single data by selecting e.g. echo $myArray[0]["name"]; 
However, I want to do a loop to iterate all names and prices from the array. Can you support me to find the bug in my code?

```
$url = "myurl";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$myArray = json_decode($response, true);


foreach ($myArray as $product) {
    echo $product->name . '<br>';
}
```

and here is a sample of the array:

```
[{
    "id": 782,
    "name": "Test Translation New",
    "price": "1",
    "image": {
        "url": "xxx/image-2.jpg",
        "position": 0
    },
    "link": "https:xxx",
    "nickname": "newmarker"
}, {
    "id": 777,
    "name": "Test Translation",
    "price": "0",
    "image": {
        "url": "https:xxx/image-1.jpg",
        "position": 0
    },
    "link": "https:xxx",
    "nickname": "newmarker"
}]
```

Comment: simply use echo $product['name'] . '<br>'; inside the foreach loop

Comment: Thx that works :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `json_decode(..., true)`, so the returned `$myArray` is an array, and all its sub items are all arrays.

```
<?php
$response = '
[{
    "id": 782,
    "name": "Test Translation New",
    "price": "1",
    "image": {
        "url": "xxx/image-2.jpg",
        "position": 0
    },
    "link": "https:xxx",
    "nickname": "newmarker"
}, {
    "id": 777,
    "name": "Test Translation",
    "price": "0",
    "image": {
        "url": "https:xxx/image-1.jpg",
        "position": 0
    },
    "link": "https:xxx",
    "nickname": "newmarker"
}]
';

$myArray = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($myArray as $product) {
    echo $product['name'] . "<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Test Translation New<br>
Test Translation<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second argument of json_decode is given and it is `true` then the returned structure is an associative array. That being said you may print the names and prices like:

```
foreach ($myArray as $product) {
    echo $product['name'] . ' - ' . $product['price'] .  '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the second argument of json_decode is given and it is true then the returned structure is an associative array. That being said you may print the names and prices like:

```
foreach ($myArray as $product) {
  echo $product['name'];
  echo (int) $product['price'];
}
```

or you can also do

```
foreach ($myArray as $product) {
  echo "{$product['name']} - {$product['price']} <br />";
}
```